# Apache NiFi to split data based on condition

Tags: apache-nifi

Our requirement is split the flow data based on condition. 
We thought to use "ExecuteStreamCommand" processor for that (intern it will use java class) but it is giving single flow data file only. We would like to have two flow data files, one is for matched and another is for unmatched criteria.

I looked at "RouteText" processor but it has no feature to use java class as part of it.

Let me know if anyone has any suggestion.

Comment: What is the condition and why do you need to use a java class?

Comment: Hi, If particular string at the specified position is "ABC" then I have to move that  message to one Kafka topic else another topic. Soi wants to get the string "ABC" dynamically from DB and check, in the future, we may add more different command types.

Comment: So stated in other terms, you have an incoming FlowFile. You want to use the result of a DB query in order to check if the result is contained in the content of the FlowFile at a specific position. Then route based on whether or not it is. Is this correct? Also what "DB" are you using? Lastly, is the content of the incoming FlowFile in a specific format?

Comment: Hi, Yes you are correct. I am using MongoDB as DB and yes I have specific format for incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [`GetMongo`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.mongodb.GetMongo/index.html) to read those definition values and store them in a map accessed by [`DistributedMapCacheClientService`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.DistributedMapCacheClientService/index.html), then use [`RouteOnContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnContent/index.html) to route the incoming flowfiles based on the absence/presence of the retrieved values.

If that doesn't work, you could instead route the query result from `GetMongo` to [`PutFile`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFile/index.html) and then use [`ScanContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ScanContent/index.html), which reads from a dictionary file on the file system and routes flowfiles based on the absence/presence of those keywords in the content.

Finally, if all else fails, you can use [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) to combine those steps into a single processor and route to `matched`/`unmatched` relationships. It processes Groovy code easily, so you can directly invoke your existing Java class if necessary.

Comment: 1st one is not working. so in 2nd option, how can we access mongo data in  "Directory File"? Do i need to 
FYI, Input to ScanContent is Mongo and ListeningPort.

Comment: You'll have to write the results of the Mongo query to a flatfile you store on disk, and depending on the output format of the query, maybe use `ReplaceText` to format it correctly. Then, use the output path of `PutFile` as the dictionary file path of `RouteOnContent` so that it reads those definitions.